How can I import CSS modules from my Node server?
I have an Express server that renders React components to a string:
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.end(renderToStaticMarkup(<App />));
});

It works as long as App doesn't import CSS modules, for example:
import styles from 'App.module.css';

export function App(){
    return <div className={styles.container}>hello</div>;
};

I get an error something like this:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

How can I import CSS modules from my Node Express server?
